# Find the first unique value in an array or string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter, find

How can I get one unique **value** in an array or string? Only the **first value**. Pure JS only.

My example:

```
function searchValue () {
  let inputText = [1,1,4,2,2,2,3,1];
  let foundedValue;
  for (let i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {
    if (i === inputText.indexOf(inputText[i]) && i === inputText.lastIndexOf(inputText[i])) {
      foundedValue = inputText[i];
      break;
    } else {
      foundedValue = "not founded.";
    }
  }
  return foundedValue;
}
console.log("Search value: "+ searchValue())
```

Answer is 4.

**But, I need a short solution. Using the `find()` and `filter()` functions.**

Answer (score 5):

You can find the first unique item in your array using [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and comparing [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) to determine whether or not there is more than one instance of an item in the array. If you need to find unique characters in a string, then you can first split it into an array and then use the same approach.

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1];
const result = arr.find((x) => arr.indexOf(x) === arr.lastIndexOf(x));
console.log(result);
// 4

const text = 'aadbbbca';
const textarr = text.split('');
const textresult = textarr.find((x) => textarr.indexOf(x) === textarr.lastIndexOf(x));
console.log(textresult);
// d
```

Comment: What if I have a string instead of an array? For example: abcd1abcd2abcd.
**Find()** does not work with string.

Comment: @Rednaksi - if you need to find the first unique character in a string (rather than the first unique value in an array), you can first split the string into an array of characters and then use the array approach with `find()`. Edited answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1];
let r = {};
arr.map(a => r[a] = (r[a] || 0) +1)
var res = arr.find(a => r[a] === 1 )
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Elegant. But I wonder if we could iterate over the array only once with reduce()?

Comment: @CodeDreamer68 sure, I can use `reduce` to build the object with frequencies.. but I'm curious how you would find the first unique element in the same function without traversing the whole array?

Comment: You have to traverse the entire array, that is a given.  But you don't have to traverse it twice.  It is a toss up between space complexity and time complexity. To traverse once you must build two maps, one tracking items found and count, the other tracking only items found once. I did it with reduce, while it isn't pretty, it is faster, because it only iterates once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use js Set() object. 
At first you could create a Set of duplicated elements.

```
const inputText = [1,1,4,2,2,2,3,1];

const duplicatesSet= inputText.reduce((dupSet, el) => 
    inputText.filter(arrEl => arrEl === el).length > 1 ?
      dupSet.add(el) : dupSet
, new Set());
```

Second you could use `array.find`. It returns first duplicated element.

```
const firstDupElement = inputText.find(el => duplicatesSet.has(el));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const searchValue = (_param) => {
  for (let i= 0; i < _param.length; i+= 1) {
    if (_param.indexOf(_param[i]) === _param.lastIndexOf(_param[i])) return _param[i];
  }
  return "not founded.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [1,1,2,2,2,1,3,1,4,4,5]

const dupelearray  = (array) => {
let arr2 =[...arr]
let ele = []
let state = false
    arr2.map((i,index)=>{
        arr2.splice(index,1)
    arr.map((j)=>{
     return arr2.includes(j) ? null : state=true
})
state && ele.push(i)
state=false
arr2.splice(index,0,i)
})
return console.log(arr.indexOf(ele[0]))
}
dupelearray(arr)
```

wow i didnt knew lastindexof method and was making this algo so difficult
btw this solution also works but definitely i am new in algo so this will take much more time but the solution still works!!!!!! damn should remember more methods or you have to think so much -_-

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).